# LocaleContextHolder.setLocale void cannot be converted to locale

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView viewMain(Locale locale) {

        Locale currentLocale = LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(Locale.US);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("locale", currentLocale);
        LOG.info("main " /* + name*/ + "page shown");
        modelAndView.setViewName("main_page");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

When i'm trying to setLocale to Locale.US i get an error that void cannot be converted to locale. But Locale.US isn't void. If i change setLocale to getLocale() everything works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Incompatible types: void cannot be converted to ..." mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369301/what-does-incompatible-types-void-cannot-be-converted-to-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because [LocaleContextHolder.setLocale() returns void](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html#setLocale-java.util.Locale-).

So just set it there and get it below:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView viewMain(Locale locale) {

        LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(Locale.US);
        Locale currentLocale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("locale", currentLocale);
        LOG.info("main " /* + name*/ + "page shown");
        modelAndView.setViewName("main_page");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```