# Method for Printing 2D Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a method to print two-dimensional arrays. I did some research and tried to apply the answers I found but it's not working with my code.

Basically I'd like to call this method

```
static void showMatrix(int[][] numbers){
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(numbers[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

here:

```
public static int[][] matrixCreate()    
{
    Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);

    int matrix[][] = new int[2][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print("[" + i + ", " + j + "]: ");
            matrix[i][j] = entry.nextInt(); 
        }
    }

    //Print New Matrix      
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
        }           
        System.out.println();
    }       

    return showMatrix(matrix);
}
```

I tried to change the return types and argument but It didn't work. Do you guys have any tips for me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Error: Incompatible types: void cannot be converted to ..." mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369301/what-does-error-incompatible-types-void-cannot-be-converted-to-mean)

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));`

Answer (score 2):

Try at the end:

```
showMatrix(matrix);
return matrix;
```

The problem being that showMatrix() doesn't return anything, so it cannot be "returned", but all you wanted was to return the matrix itself anyway.

And welcome to SO, let me know if this isn't detailed enough, I could look at it more but this just looked like something that definitely wouldn't work as is.

To make your life simpler in the future--you might consider downloading eclipse or intellij... for a new java user they will be invaluable for helping you with syntax problems--a real life saver.