# java mapping array of values to index of odd values

Tags: java, java-stream

Here's my code:

```
int []a = {1,2,3,4,5,7};

Arrays.stream(a)
      .map((n, i) -> i)
      .filter(n -> a[n] % 2 == 1)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

I'm trying to print the INDEX of all odd numbers. Everything seems fine except the map. It returns an error saying:

> Error: `<lambda parameter>` can not be converted to int.

I somewhat understand why it happens, but I do not know how to work around it.

NOTE: This is not the same as expecting a return from a void method. This was a faulty understanding of generics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Incompatible types: void cannot be converted to ..." mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369301/what-does-incompatible-types-void-cannot-be-converted-to-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print the indices of all odd numbers, I would start with the range of valid indices. Like,

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 };
IntStream.range(0, a.length).filter(i -> a[i] % 2 == 1).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,7};
IntStream.range(0, a.length)
         .filter(e -> a[e] % 2 == 1)
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Which will output:

```
0
2
4
5
```

Which uses [`IntStream::range`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) to create a `Stream` of integers from 0 to `a.length` and then if the element of `a` at that index is odd, it will print it out.