# Incompatible types: void cannot be converted to ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm new to coding. I have a function which generates an ArrayList of random integers and then returns that ArrayList. When I try to assign that ArrayList to an ArrayList in my main function I get this error: Test.java:36: error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to ArrayList
List=randomnumbers.GenerateArray(highestnum);

*Array Generator Class*

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Random;
  
class ArrayGenerator{

  //Create varibles and ArrayList and Random
  int highestnum;
  ArrayList <Integer> randomnumberArray = new ArrayList<>();
  Random random = new Random();
  

  //Constructor
  public ArrayGenerator(int highestnum){
    this.highestnum = highestnum;
  }

  //GenerateArray function
   public ArrayList<Integer> GenerateArray(int highestnum){

     //Loop to generate 20 random numbers
     for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
          int randomInt = random.nextInt(highestnum);
            randomnumberArray.add(randomInt);

            
  }
     return randomnumberArray;
    
   }
}
```

*Part of Main Function*

```
 ArrayList <Integer> List = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayGenerator randomnumbers = new ArrayGenerator(highestnum);

  //Create array of random numbers and assign it to List

    List=randomnumbers.GenerateArray(highestnum);
```

How do I fix this?

I tried doing this and didn't work.

```
ArrayList <Integer> List = new ArrayList<>(randomnumbers.GenerateArray(highestnum));
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce (`ideone.com`)](https://ideone.com/B87Ekc).

Comment: As an aside: Method- and variable names should start with a lowercase letter (`List` -> `list`, `GenerateArray` -> `generateArray`)

Comment: Please edit the question to show a [complete but minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We should be able to copy-and-paste your code into our IDE and get the same result.

Comment: Take a look at this question:  [What does "Incompatible types: void cannot be converted to ..." mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369301/what-does-incompatible-types-void-cannot-be-converted-to-mean) . See how it applies to your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message states that there is a method that returns `void` and you attempt to assign the result of such method to an `ArrayList` variable. You will need to find the exact position of your error and trace it back to the place where your code tries to assign the result of a `void` method to an `ArrayList` variable. You create `randomnumbers` like this:

```
ArrayGenerator randomnumbers = new ArrayGenerator(highestnum);
```

and then later you have

```
List=randomnumbers.GenerateArray(highestnum);
```

which fails due to such an assignment.

If we try your code then as it is it does not reproduce your problem, therefore your code is at least slightly different in reality from the code that you shared. The culprit will be a place where you assign the result of a `void` method to an `ArrayList`. You should find the culprit with the help of a debugger and from there on it will be an easy fix.